# Reuse laravel validation rules from another controller

Tags: php, laravel

**Q:** How can i reuse Auth's *ResigsterController* validation rules from another controller without having to grab the whole *RegisterController* class?
Here are the rules:

```
...

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'tos' => 'boolean|accepted',
    ]);
}
...
```

The other controller in:
app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    //I need to validate $request with the rules from
    //ControllersAuth\RegisterController.php
}
```

Comment: You can create a trait for form request validation and use when you need...

Comment: Check my answer if you want to go with trait, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To reuse same validation rules you can use [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use trait. *Create a trait like:*

```
trait ValidationTrait {
    public $errors;

    public function validate($data) {
        $Reflection = new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $ReflectionClass = $Reflection->newInstance();
        if(empty($ReflectionClass->rules)) return TRUE;

        $v = Validator::make($data, $ReflectionClass->rules);

        if($v->fails()) {
            $this->errors = $v->failed();
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function validationErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

*In model:*

```
class myModel extends Eloquent {
    use ValidationTrait;

    public $rules = array(
        'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'tos' => 'boolean|accepted',
    );
}
```

*Call it like:*

```
$myModel = new myModel();

if($myModel->validate(Input::all()) {
    //validate success....
}else{
    return $Customer->validationErrors()
}
```

Comment: Bad practice to add validation in Model. Best practice is always to keep it in sepearte request file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using creating a Helper class so you can have some of your code's reusable in any class.

If you don't know how to make a Helper class there are guides [here](https://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a file request add the validation rule there, next time u need it, you can call the file name,ex:

```
    public function update(UserRequest $request,User $user){
}



//1. Php artisan make:request UserRequest
//2. add rule to UserRequest file
public function rules()
        {
            return [
               'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'tos' => 'boolean|accepted',
            ];
        }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation